# Office 365 and smartphone address list

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, exchange, intune

In our company, we use Office 365 and we want to reach all employees' phone numbers from our company mobile phones that have Outlook installed. I know it is possible, but i don't know how I can do it.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you wish to call all employee mobile phones simultaneous with a voice converence call, with a SMS text message, or something else? Please click [edit] and clarify your request. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: We use o365 and users updated their profile so they entered their phone numbers on o365. Is it posible that can i see employee's number on my smartphone phonebook. I know other organization can do it but how ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Mobile apps and smartphones are off-topic on this site, but there are sister sites that handle those questions, depending on the platform.  For example, https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/, https://apple.stackexchange.com/, https://android.stackexchange.com/.